# Spring: transaction propagation

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, transactions, spring-transactions

I have the following code:

```
@Transactional
public void handle() {
    for (Item item : getItems()) {
        handle(item);
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
public void handle(Item item) {
    /* logic here */
}
```

Say the loop in `handle()` processes 10 items. Also assume that for 3 items `handle(Item)` will throw an exception.

My questions:

[1] Will the outer transaction be committed after the 10th item? This means that the necessary changes for 7 items will be committed and that any intermediate changes for the 3 other items will be rolled back to the savepoint as created?

[2] Will the exception in `handle(Item)` be caught and not be forwarded to `handle()` then? Is this done by `@Transactional`?

[3] In addition, I would like to understand what the difference in behavior with the following flow is:

```
@Transactional
public void handle() {
    for (Item item : getItems()) {
        handle(item);
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void handle(Item item) {
    /* logic here */
}
```

From my understanding from the docs, here a new transaction will be started and the active transaction will be suspended. This differs from `NESTED`, where a savepoint is created and the current transaction is still being used. But I believe that also here with `REQUIRES_NEW` the changes for 7 items will be committed and that any intermediate changes for the other 3 items will be forgotten.

So what is the real difference then (if any)?

Comment: In this case you have only one transaction.it will be commited or bollback . There is no outer ttansaction

Comment: @sbjavateam Care to explain?

Comment: you call one transaction method from another transaction method inside same service. spring transaction work with proxy,in you case spring doesn't start new transaction for second call

Comment: @sbjavateam This should work with AspectJ?

Comment: with AspectJ - yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NESTED starts subtransaction of a main one. REQUIRES_NEW starts separate transaction.

If you mark a method with the REQUIRES_NEW after method exit data remains in DB (committed by the separate transaction) no matter what happens with outer transaction.

In case of NESTED the changes are rollbacked if outer transaction is rolled back.

See answers [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/7372-propagation-nested-versus-propagation-requires-new)

Comment: I see. And that about the exceptions? Will `NESTED` or `REQUIRES_NEW` `@Transactional` swallow the exception (and do its rollback logic), to prevent the outer or parent transaction from also rolling back?

Comment: Transactional does not swallow exception. It catches, does rollback in the catch, and rethrow to let you process real exception. So in your case suppose third `handle(item);` throws and exception. In case of REQUIRES_NEW 2 previous calls remain in DB in case of NESTED the 2 previous calls are rolled back with main transaction.

Comment: Got it! And what is a clean way to swallow the exceptions? Is this possible with annotations? In my case, I want to process as much items as possible. So if item 3 crashes, we should proceed to item 4, 5, 6, ... The main/parent transaction should never be rolled back.

Comment: Wrap the `handle(item);` into try/catch and just continue on catch. Add the REQUIRES_NEW for the `handle(item);`. I think it's enough.

Answer (score 1):

> From my understanding from the docs, here a new transaction will be
>   started and the active transaction will be suspended.

1. if method handle() and handle(Item item) inside one service , only one transaction will be started - for first method.  It's called self-invocation. see :

[A Spring hard fact about transaction management](https://blog.frankel.ch/a-spring-hard-fact-about-transaction-management/#gsc.tab=0) and 
[WHAT IS A TRANSACTION?](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/java/common-oversights-utilizing-nested-transactions-spring/).

to apply transaction for handle(Item item) inside handle() you should

```
    @Transactional
    public void handle() {
       for (Item item : getItems()) {
         applicationContext.getBean(your service).handle(item); 
       }
    }

or use spring aspectj load time weaving for self-invocation (inside one service call one method from another)
```

Call method with Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW inside loop it's bad for performance ,  you create new transaction for each call. You can wrap inside one method but with handling exception - only for exception related to businesses logic! not all types of exceptions

```
@Transactional
public void handle() {
        ..some logic
        //if you really need it
        applicationContext.getBean(your service).handleBatch(getItems());
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void handleBatch(Collection items) {
    for (Item item : items) {
        applicationContext.getBean(your service).handle(item)
    }
}

public void handle(Item item) {
   try{ 
      //do operation
      }catch(.appropriate type..Exception ex){
         //log exception!!!
   }
}
```

2. about rollback : spring does rolling back on RuntimeException and Error but not on checked exceptions.
   if you  method throws some  checked exception, changes will be commited.
   to avoid commit use

   > @Transactional(rollbackFor=CheckedException.class)